# MySQL select dynamic row values as column Name

Tags: mysql

I have the following details in my table

## stock table

```
id sale stock item_code branch
1   0    200   abc       A
2   100  200   abc       A
3   0    200   def       B
4   100  200   def       B
5   0    200   xyz       B
6   100  200   xyz       A
```

And, her is my expected output:

```
item_code    A-sale  A-stock     B-sale   B-stock 
abc           100      400       null      null  
def           null    null        100       400
xyz           100      200         0        200
```

How can I manage to get this output from the stock table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
    item_code,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN branch = 'A' THEN sale
        ELSE 0
    END) 'A-sale',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN branch = 'A' THEN stock
        ELSE 0
    END) 'A-stock',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN branch = 'B' THEN sale
        ELSE 0
    END) 'B-sale',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN branch = 'B' THEN stock
        ELSE 0
    END) 'B-stock'
FROM
    stock
GROUP BY item_code
```

Comment: Thats the same answer as mine you only changed the syntax a bit!

Comment: And Sagi your this kind of comment is quite childish. And it shows that you are hungry for gaining reputation only. I respect others' opinions and values and the same I expect from others. You know very well that different users might approach this problem in almost the same way. Thank you@Sagi

Comment: Yes, I do, and there is only two ways - conditional aggregation and pivot.You provided the exact same answer as mine, I really don't care about reputation just don't post an answer and claim it as your own!

Answer (score 0):

```
select item_code,
    case when branch ='A' Then max(sale) end as A-sale,
    case when branch ='A' Then sum(stock)as A-stock,
    case when branch ='B' Then max(sale) end as B-sale,
    case when branch ='B' Then sum(stock)as B-stock
from table_name
group by item_code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    item_code,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN branch = 'A' THEN sale
        ELSE 0
    END) 'A-sale',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN branch = 'A' THEN stock
        ELSE 0
    END) 'A-stock',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN branch = 'B' THEN sale
        ELSE 0
    END) 'B-sale',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN branch = 'B' THEN stock
        ELSE 0
    END) 'B-stock'
FROM
    stock
GROUP BY item_code
```

Let me know it's working or not